# Message user for being idle

Tags: javascript

I already have auto logout snippet and now I want the user to know that they are being idle for about minutes.

What is the easiest way to message user for being idle in 1 hour? Can this be done in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would proably use some code that is already written and tested. I suggest taking a look at Paul Irish's jQuery [Idle timer](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/) plugin or Nicholas Zachas' [JavaScript](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/02/detecting-if-the-user-is-idle-with-javascript-and-yui-3/) version; ( which Paul based his off )